# How to copy the contents of an ArrayList in another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public boolean isConnectedTo(Suspect aSuspect){

    boolean flag = false;
    Registry tempRegistry = new Registry();
    ArrayList<Communication> TempComms = new ArrayList<Communication>(tempRegistry.GetComms());


    for(Communication comms : TempComms) {
        System.out.println("here");
        for(String PhoneNums : phoneNumbers){
            if(PhoneNums.equals(comms.GetTransmitter())) {
                for(String numbers : aSuspect.getNumbersList()) {
                    if(numbers.equals(comms.GetReceiver())) 
                        flag = true;
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    return flag;

}
```

So I am trying to create a program that among other things, it will search two ArrayLists(TempComs and phoneNumbers) and it will return true or false whether a string in the first is the same with a string in the second or not. I create the new `ArrayList TempComms` with the method `tempRegistry.GetComms()`. `GetComms()` is a method in another class, (class Registry) and has just a `return communications;` command, communications is an ArrayList in the class Registry.(The `ArrayList phoneNumbers` is an arrayList of the class the code is into.) So normally with with

```
ArrayList<Communication> TempComms = new ArrayList<Communication>(tempRegistry.GetComms());
```

the `ArrayList TempComms` must be the same with `ArrayList communication` that exists in the other class. But I figured out that for some reason the problem is in  TempComms, because the first for is never running(For that reason I used  `System.out.println("here");` but it never printed). I searched and tried a lot to find the solution of this problem of my own, but I didn't manage to make some progress, so I would be grateful if someone who knows where's the problem or what I do wrong tell me about it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If `here` isn't printed, it means `TempComms` is empty, which means that whatever `tempRegistry.GetComms()` returns is empty. This is a fact.

Comment: tempRegistry.GetComms() returns an ArrayList communications, but the ArrayList communications can't be empty because I tried to print the ArrayList communications with another method long before the method I am trying to pass its contents and its contents are printed as normall.

Comment: It is empty. It is the only possibility given with that code (hence my "This is a fact" in my first comment).

Comment: How it can be empty but when I use a for() to print its contents, I get all the contets I have added to that ArrayList with the command communications.add(something) ?

Comment: I don't know why it's empty, I only know it **is** empty. If I had to guess, it's empty because you've made an error somewhere.

Comment: Ok, it is empty but whenever I use that commad below, it works fine.
`public void printCommunications() {
  
  for(Communication comms: communications)
   comms.printInfo();
 }`

Comment: Just because a part of a code works, doesn't mean you don't have a bug.

Comment: You were right in a way. The problem was that the object in main had an array list communications with contets, but I was trying to use an other Registry object in another class than main, while its ArrayList communications was an empty list. Thanks for the help and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the Registry which contains a list (comms).

```
Registry tempRegistry = new Registry();
```

Then you are trying to get that comm list by calling `tempRegistry.GetComms()` .

Unless you are populating this communication list in the constructor Registry() (not only instantiating, you should add some entries as well),
that list will be empty when for loop is called.

(Because you are clearly **NOT** populating it after creating the instance **tempRegistry** and before calling the for loop.

```
ArrayList<Communication> TempComms = new ArrayList<Communication>(tempRegistry.GetComms());


    for(Communication comms : TempComms) {
```

Therefore, the TempComms list is also an empty list. Which is why the inside code of the for loop is not executing.

Comment: Hmmmm thank you..! Now I get where is the problem. I altered my code and now it works fine. Thanks again!